# How to edit DsoFramer 1.3?

Tags: excel, visual-c++, dsoframer

I'm using [DsoFramer](http://codebetter.com/blogs/paul.laudeman/archive/2006/05/25/Registration_2D00_Free-COM-with-the-DsoFramer-Control.aspx) 1.3 in my project to hold Excel (2007) documents. But it have a big problem, that is:

All the Excel documents opened by DsoFramer share only one Excel process. The result is when the second Excel document opened by the DsoFramer, the first document is uneditable.

Even more, when I double click an Excel document in Windows Explorer directly, the documents in the DsoFramer will lose focus, because only one `excel.exe` in the task manager, the last will get it.

Fortunately, microsoft supplies the source code of DsoFramer 1.3, though does not support it.
(http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=CE2CA4FD-2169-4FAC-82AF-770AA9B60D77&displaylang=en.)

How do I edit the source code then make it generate a new Excel process when opening a Excel document using dsoframer every time?

I have taken a try to [Steve](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22472/steve)'s method, but it doesn't work.
[DSOFramer closing Excel doc in another window. If unsaved data in file, dsoframer fails to open with "Attempt to access invalid address"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251909/dsoframer-closing-excel-doc-in-another-window-if-unsaved-data-in-file-dsoframer)

Answer (score 0):

You might try [SpreadsheetGear](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) which comes with a [Windows Forms control](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/samples/windowsforms.aspx) which provides the ability to view, edit, format, print, etc... xls and xlsx workbooks. We have a number of customers who have switched from the DsoFramer to SpreadsheetGear for various reasons.

SpreadsheetGear has the concept of a workbook set which is a collection of workbooks and is roughly analogous to an instance of the Excel application. The number of workbook sets is limited only by available memory. It also has a WorkbookView Windows Forms control. You can have multiple WorkbookViews, and each WorkbookView has it's own workbook set by default (you can override this if you want multiple WorkbookViews to view the same workbook set).

You can learn more about SpreadsheetGear and download the free trial [here](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/).

Disclaimer: I own SpreadsheetGear LLC

Answer (score 0):

The office ocx 7 hasn't the issue. It seems like an enhanced version dsoframer and solved some fateful bugs existed in the dsoframer.