# Prevent opening a file

Tags: c#, file, docx, dsoframer

I am using dsoFramer to open docx files in winforms. When a docx file is opened in dsoframer and user open the same document from windows explorer, the application becomes unstable. How can I prevent opening the file from windows explorer when it is open in dsoFramer.

Best regards.

Comment: dup? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/861489/how-to-edit-dsoframer-1-3

Comment: You'll need to give up on DsoFramer, it is no longer available from MSFT.  All downloads links have been removed.  There are no known workarounds for its flaws.  Switch to Office automation with, say, VSTO instead.

Answer (score 1):

i would create a copy of the file and work from that, if you need to save it then just replace the original with the copy

Comment: Hi harryovers and thank you for your suggestion, this is what I'm doing, a temporary docx file (with hidden as attribute) is created in C:\Documents and Settings\<user>\Local Settings\Application Data, but user still has possibility to open the file. I want a way to prevent the file from being opened.